# Regex find 0 by itself not inside another number. Remove whitespace and "0"

Tags: regex, replace, find

I need to find instances of just whitespace or a 0
NOT 01 or 10 or any other number containing 0 just an isolated 0

I knew that this would find any non zero number (01 would be okay and 10)
But taking the reverse did not hold up for some reason

```
^(\d*[1-9]\d*)$
```

EXAMPLES to FIND

- 0
- [blank space optional] 0 [blank space optional]
- [blank space] [blank space optional]

What NOT to find

- 01
- 10
- 125510456

Comment: You need to give examples. Are you matching `0` or whitespace?

Comment: thank you I just edited to include examples. Is below answer proper way to find zero by itself , just spaces, or spaces and a single 0

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way to do it:

```
re = /
  ^
  (?!.*0.*0) # at most one 0
  [0 ]+ # all chars must be 0 or space
  $
/x

["0", " 0 ", "0 ", " 0", " ", "  "].all?{|s| s.match re}
#=> true
["01", "00", "10", "125510456"].any?{|s| s.match re}
#=> false
```

Comment: thank you pguardiario. 
Do you know why I would get a syntax error when combining the above like so  `/^(?!.*0.*0)[0 ]$/x`   ...

Comment: Don't forget the `+` and try leaving out the `x`.

Answer (score 0):

I have it ALMOST figured out
This will find 0 by itself

```
^([0]|\s)$
```

And this will do the full replace of whitespace or 0 by itself

```
var text = $(this).text().replace(/\s*^([0]|\s)$/g, '');
```

**QUESTION: Am I missing something with the spaces?**
Did I make spaces before and after optional?
It seems to work here

http://www.regextester.com/21
(substitute for the regex above)

Comment: a0b, a0 or 0b is not a concern to you?

Comment: right and that's why I'm  having such an issue. Finding any zero isn't much of a challenge. I need to find "0" by itself (with or without spaces) or just whitespace.

Comment: I'm sorry what about the following case 0000001?

Comment: I would not be looking to replace that. So I would not want to find it.
Meaning the regex should not include that.
My ultimate goal is to hide rows that have only spaces or have just a single "0" as the answer.

Comment: Your regexp means:
`\s*^([0]|\s)$`

Space or tab once or more times, followed by a line beginning, after one "0" or one space or tab, and line end.

Answer (score 0):

According your comment, matches if in a line only one 0 character or any number of spaces (space only!).

```
^(0|\ +)$
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/eK0eF4/4)

Comment: Realistically there will only be JUST spaces (whitespace), JUST the number 0, or a combination of alpha-numberic characters which may have a zero somewhere in the number sequence. I'm trying to find the first two possibilities.

Answer (score 0):

I think you may be looking for whitespace boundary type of enforcement.

`\s?(?<!\S)0(?!\S)\s?|\s\s?`

Formatted:

```
    \s?                # Optional whitespace
    (?<! \S )          # Whitespace boundary behind
    0                  # Required Literal '0'
    (?! \S )           # Whitespace boundary ahead
    \s?                # Optional whitespace
 |                   # or,
    \s                 # Required whitespace
    \s?                # Optional whitespace
```

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> ^([0]|\s)$
> ```
>
> **QUESTION: Am I missing something with the spaces?** Did I make spaces before and after optional?

This expression matches a single zero as well as a single space; it does neither match a zero with space before or after nor multiple spaces.

The simple expression `/^\s*0?\s*$/` will match a string

- `^\s*` beginning with any number of whitespace characters
- `0?` maybe a zero
- `\s*$` ending with any number of whitespace characters

```js
var texts = [ "0", "  0  ", "   ", "What NOT to find", "01", "10", "125510456"];
for (i in texts)
  document.write(texts[i].replace(/^\s*0?\s*$/, '"$&" MATCHED'), "<p>");
```